# line-through style for a spark label

Tags: apache-flex, styles

How can I set a line-through style for a `s:label` like css `text-decoration:line-through`.

.

Comment: Don't think you can. You'll have to use a component that supports html formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a style on  called `lineThrough`.  It is a `Boolean` so just set it to `true`.

---

Documentation:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html#style:lineThrough

in `spark.components.Label.as` there is an `include "../styles/metadata/BasicInheritingTextStyles.as"` and that file contains the following snippit defining `lineThrough`

```
/** 
 *  If true, applies strikethrough, a line drawn through the middle of the text.  
 *  
 *  <p><b>For the Spark theme, see
 *  flashx.textLayout.formats.ITextLayoutFormat.lineThrough</b></p>
 *
 *  <p><b>For the Mobile theme, this is not supported.</b></p>
 * 
 *  @see flashx.textLayout.formats.ITextLayoutFormat#lineThrough
 * 
 *  @langversion 3.0
 *  @playerversion Flash 10
 *  @playerversion AIR 1.5
 *  @productversion Flex 4
 */
[Style(name="lineThrough", type="Boolean", inherit="yes")]
```